# Should prepositions be repeated?

Tags: grammar, preposition

I am writing a formal letter in German, and asked myself a question:

**Should I repeat prepositions in a series?**

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und Ihre schnelle Antwort.
>
> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und für Ihre schnelle Antwort.

I know English has somewhat [loose rules](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=409020) about this, while French is [much stricter](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=968213), but cannot find anything for German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely leave out preposition and pronoun (or possessive) if both objects agree in gender, number, case and attributes (i.e. adjectives mostly):

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und Antwort.

It may still be acceptable to do so if two mismatching genders, numbers or cases share a common inflective morpheme:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und **Antworten**.

You should repeat at least the pronoun if the first object has an attribute but the second has none, because otherwise it will be applied to both:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre **geschätzte** Aufmerksamkeit und **[geschätzte]** Antwort.
>
> *<s>Vielen Dank für Ihre **hohe** Aufmerksamkeit und **[*hohe]** Antwort.</s>
>
> Vielen Dank für Ihre **hohe** Aufmerksamkeit und **(für) Ihre** Antwort.
>
> Vielen Dank für Ihre **hohe** Aufmerksamkeit und **schnelle** Antwort.

That is why it is sometimes clever to put the one with attribute last, as in your original example:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und **schnelle** Antwort.

The long form is never wrong, of course:

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und **für Ihre (schnelle)** Antwort.

You should also repeat pronoun and preposition if the first object has lots of attributes. It can even be useful to repeat more (*vielen Dank* in this case) or paraphrase it.

> Vielen Dank für Ihre **(…)** Aufmerksamkeit und **danke für Ihre (schnelle)** Antwort.

Applying redundancy to *Aufmerksamkeit* and *Antwort* in particular may still feel wrong, though, because the former is an abstract noun without a plural.

> Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und **Ihre (schnelle)** Antwort.

PS: Misleading and uncommon redundancy has been used for comedic effect frequently. Heinz Erhardt comes to mind.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, with all the example that I needed.
*Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und Antwort!* :)

Answer (score 7):

In this example there is no need for redundancy, and, hence, the first version is better. The second is not wrong, though.

Comment: And you can even say " Vielen Dank für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit und schnelle Antwort."

Comment: Could you give an example where the redundancy would be accepted?

Comment: It is an often used rhetorical device to repeat something. In this situation, there is redundancy, but it has a purpose.